# Configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to restart after auto update on weekends only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, windows-update

[This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mu/archive/2008/10/02/windows-update-and-automatic-reboots.aspx) provides excellent guide on how to change group policy to prevent windows update to restart the server. However we don't want to hold back applying important update for too long. Is there any way we set windows to restart after auto-update on weekends only?

I know one obvious solution is to create a task scheduler to run `shutdown /r /t 0` and schedule it to repeat every weekend. Is there any other method than this -- some hidden settings on windows update maybe? We don't want to restart the server if not required by windows update.

Answer (score 1):

Wuinstall (3rd party exe) or PowerShell queries for windows update do the trick nicely. I've used both methods in the past.

Combine either of these with a scheduled task and you have the behavior requested.

Comment: +1. Basically from the other side - do not use integrated automatisms but have a task doing an update run on the weekend, followed possibly by a restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a managed update service then man up and do it manually.  IMO you don't want to be blindly installing the updates and auto-restarting at the weekend.  That way you won't know until Monday morning that one of the updates FUBARd your server.

Set the updates to download automatically but manually install, and then just log in at the weekend, review, approve and install the updates, reboot, wait for the server to come back online again, check all services running correctly, check the updates installed OK, review the event logs.

We know that every now and then updates will go wrong, so trying to go completely hands-off isn't necessarily recommended.

Comment: While this is an ok approach for smaller organizations it does **not** scale well. The concept of checking availability and service states is good but that should be automated as well (nagios, etc).

Comment: I did say 'if you're not using a managed update service'.  Obviously if you DO have a management system then you don't need to mess about with scripts to install the updates 'blind', which I felt the OP was suggesting.